# Causality in Dirac delta forced harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

If I take the simple forced harmonic oscillator equation, apply the Fourier transform to both sides, and assuming the forcing function is a Dirac delta function (at the origin) I get:

$ F(s) = \frac 1 {1-4\pi^2s^2} $

If I then take the inverse Fourier transform I see my wave like behaviour as expected (after t=0). However what I do not understand is why is there oscillatory behaviour before t=0? That seems to violate causality. Similar postings seem to suggest just defining f(t) to be zero before the impulse, or using the Laplace transform.

This is closely related to other postings, but it is the causality issue which is confusing me, I don't understand why the fourier method seems to break it.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, it may be easier to discuss the question if you include the "forced harmonic oscillator equation" you are referring to and the inverse transform.

Comment: Actually, I have realised it is less to do with causality than to do with boundary conditions.

Comment: Actually, I have realised it is less to do with causality than to do with boundary conditions. There was a good explanation on math stack exchange (which unfortunately I can't now find). Basically, there are multiple spectra where each spectra is associated with a different boundary condition. The connection with causality is that most people (reasonably) assume a boundary condition where there is no initial movement. Unfortunately many people seem to quote the same formula as I used in my post, but this does not meet that condition. Hence the confusion.